# How to detect a minimized window on top of current active screen?

Tags: javascript, html

The purpose for this task is that I want to detect cheaters in an online test who open a new browser to search for answers. The test already has conditions where the user cannot minimize the active full screen tab or open another tab. However it is still possible that some users might try to use a minimized window which stays on top to cheat. Anyway to detect such infractions?

Comment: Is the window blur event not sufficient?